# What are the Delegate methods of modal view?

Tags: objective-c

Which delegate method will be called after dismissing the modal view?

Answer (score 0):

The following methods will be called.

As for the viewController will appear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(bool)animated;
-(void)viewDidAppear:(bool)animated;
```

As for the viewController will disappear:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(bool)animated;
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(bool)animated;
```